# Formatting entered text in Python Tkinter Entry widget after user interacts with another widget

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

If a user enters 25000 into a tkinter entry widget, is there a way to make the widget automatically display the text that was just entered as $25,000.00 once the user interacts with anything else? I've used '${:.,2f}'.format() in other projects, but I'm not sure how to use it with tkinter. Perhaps there is another method entirely when building code in tkinter. Thanks in advance for any advice you might have to offer!

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
window=Tk()
window.title("APY Accrued Value Calculator")

def Button1Function():
    exit()

def Button2Function(Entry1,Entry2,Entry3):
    while True:
        if Entry1==0 or Entry2==0 or Entry3==0:
            messagebox.showerror("Error Detected","All fields must have a 
number value greater than zero")
            return None
        if Entry3==int(Entry3):
            Entry3=int(Entry3)
        else:
            messagebox.showerror("Error Detected","Number of years must be 
a whole number.")
            return None
        try:
            if Entry2==int(Entry2):
                Entry2=int(Entry2)
        except: pass
        AccruingAmount=Entry1
        for i in range(0,Entry3):
            AccruingAmount=AccruingAmount*(1+(Entry2/100))
        Entry1='${:,.2f}'.format(Entry1)
        Entry2='{}%'.format(Entry2)
        AccruingAmount='${:,.2f}'.format(AccruingAmount)
        message="                                                                                                                                                              
"
        CalculationMessage=Message(window,width=345,text=message)
        message="If "+Entry1+" is deposited and left for "+str(Entry3)+" 
years at an annual interest rate of "+Entry2+", your final return will be: 
"+AccruingAmount+"."
        CalculationMessage=Message(window,width=345,text=message)
        CalculationMessage.grid(row=12,column=0,sticky=(N),pady=(5,0))
        break

Label1=Label(window,text="Starting amount:")
Label1.grid(column=0,sticky=(W),padx=(5,0))

StrVar1=StringVar()

Entry1=Entry(window,textvariable=StrVar1)
Entry1.grid(column=0,sticky=(W),padx=(5,0))

Label2=Label(window,text="APY percentage rate:")
Label2.grid(row=3,column=0,sticky=(W),padx=(5,0),pady=(10,0))

StrVar2=StringVar()
Entry2=Entry(window, textvariable=StrVar2)
Entry2.grid(column=0,sticky=(W),padx=(5,0))

Label3=Label(window,text="Number of years that starting amount will be 
accruing interest:")
Label3.grid(row=6,column=0,columnspan=2,sticky=(W),padx=(5,0),pady=(10,0))

StrVar3=StringVar()
Entry3=Entry(window, textvariable=StrVar3)
Entry3.grid(row=7,column=0,sticky=(W),padx=(5,0))

BlankRow3=Label(window,text="Calculation results:",font=("bold"))
BlankRow3.grid(row=8,column=0,pady=(10,0))

CalculationBox=Canvas(window,borderwidth=2,width=350,height=25)
CalculationBox.grid(row=12,column=0)

Button1=Button(window,text="Close",width=12,command=Button1Function)
Button1.grid(row=13,column=0,sticky=(W),padx=(5,0),pady=(0,5))

try:
    Button2=Button(window,text="Calculate",width=12,command=lambda: Button2Function(float(Entry1.get()),float(Entry2.get()),float(Entry3.get())))
    Button2.grid(row=13,column=0,sticky=(E),padx=(0,5),pady=(0,5))
except: messagebox.showerror("Error Detected","Numbers must be entered 
into all fields.")

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: And will you not show us your code?

Comment: This is my first post on Stack Overflow. How do you share code? I tried pasting it into the comment box, but it didn't turn out well...

Comment: Edit your question and paste the code there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
amount = tk.Label(root,text = "$0.00")
amount.grid(row=1,column=0)
def updat():
    try:amount.config(text="${:,.2f}".format(float(entry.get())))
    except:amount.config(text = "$0.00")
entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.grid(row=0,column=0)
entry.bind("<Key>",lambda v: root.after(10,updat))
root.mainloop()
```

Running:

[image: output]

Comment: Excellent! That might be just what I need. I'll tinker with it in my program and let you know how it works out! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hello, I know this is an old post, but I have a similar problem. Is there a way to do the same thing, with the difference of inserting the updated text into that same entry box in real time? I have a feeling that this is not possible